# unable to hide rows/ shrink listview items in a list view using visible property and mvvm binding

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android

I have a toggle button and list (which has rows or labels, stack-layout in a grid). Toggle(Switch) and List View are declared in Xaml file where list's Data-cell is generated programmatically in cs file. I need to hide/show this stack layout which is inside the list based on the toggle switch.

I have achieved this by creating a boolean field in the object of the list and assigning it to true when toggle is enabled. And using this field in ISvisiblePraperty of the stacklayout

```
stacklayout.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, new Binding("SubItemSectionVisible", BindingMode.Default, new BooleanConverterForSubItem()));
```

Now i can see the text inside stacklayout is hiding and visible based on the toggle but the list item size is not shrinking.
i have to scroll the list once to see the listview items shrink or expand.
Is there a way to achieve this shrink as soon as I click toggle?

This issue is only in iOS, in android it's working fine as expected.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this with a Grid instead of a StackLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing new with Xamarin Forms iOS.  It's been around for a while and to be completely honest with you, I'm not sure if a proper (performant) solution was ever supplied by Xamarin but if it does exist, then ignore the below.  :-)

This has existed for a while ...

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/DynamicUnevenListCells/

... but was always a really non-performant approach.  Worth a try, otherwise, I overcame it by creating a custom renderer.

**Custom Control**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourApplication.Controls
{
    public class CustomListView : ListView
    {
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemHeightChangedEvent;

        public void ItemHeightChanged(int index)
        {
            ItemHeightChangedEvent?.Invoke(this, index);
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom iOS Renderer**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using UIKit;
using System.ComponentModel;
using YourApplication.Controls;
using Foundation;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomListView), typeof(YourApplication.iOS.CustomListViewRenderer))]

namespace YourApplication.iOS
{
    public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        private CustomListView _formsListView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            _formsListView = Element as CustomListView;

            if (_formsListView == null)
                return;

            _formsListView.ItemHeightChangedEvent += async (object sender, int index) =>
            {
                Control.ReloadRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(index, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<localControls:CustomListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" ... >
```

You'll need to read up on the creation of custom renderers (if you're not already familiar with how to use them) and then all you need to do is, call the `ItemHeightChanged` method on the item when the cell changes.

Performance can be questionable (hence why only attack the items that have changed) but it worked for me.

I hope that makes sense and more so, I hope it helps.

Comment: I used your code, ios custom renderer is executing only during initial page appearing. When i switch toggle renderer code is not executing. Hence rows are not yet shrinking. I need to scroll the list view to see the shrink and expand of list items. @Skin

Comment: @SaiSunkari you have to invoke the event. The initial call to OnElementChanged initializes the ItemHeightChangedEvent event. From your forms implementation, you need to call that for the item index when your item height changes, so by the sounds of it, you need to call it from your toggle event. Make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure how you went with that but another way to overcome your issue might be to consider looking at using a CollectionView.